# How can the normality of the distribution of variables from a very large sample be checked?

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a sample with 10 000 observations and I would like to test the normality of the distribution of the variables in this sample in order to work on Z-scores. Shapiro-Wilk and Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests seem to reach their limits on such a large sample. I drawn qqplots but I wonder if it could be sufficient ?

Thanks for your answers !
Claire

Comment: Both tests are sensitive to the larger samples, it would be better to try the Q-Q plot, Normal probability plot or histograms. These plot will give a clear and good visualization if the sample size is large.
This thread might help https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_we_know_which_test_to_apply_for_testing_normality